# How can I use a dropdown in my angular2 form to submit an object

Tags: node.js, forms, mongodb, drop-down-menu, angular

I have an application that will include Topics which contain Articles. When the user creates an article, I want them to select a topic to associate the article with from a dropdown that presents the available topics. The UI side of this presents the user with a form that looks correct at the moment, however, the topic object is not being passed with the form and I cant understand why. Can someone please help me understand how this should be done?

the relevant pieces here are below:
This is the select statement in my form that properly displays the options for topics that I want to present to the user.

```
                <select [ngFormControl]="myForm.find('topic')" id="topic"  class="form-control" required>
                    <option  *ngFor="let a of topics" [value]="a">{{a.title}}</option>
                </select>
```

When I try to verify that I received the data I'm looking for I get an 'undefined' error with this line:

```
console.log(this.myForm.value.topic.title);
```

If I do this I get [object, object]

```
console.log(this.myForm.value.topic);
```

what gets submitted to the service is this:

```
Object { content: "8th content", title: "8th title", articleId: "57588eaf1ac787521d15ac34", username: "Jason", userId: Object, topicId: undefined }
```

Can someone please help me understand what I'm missing here to be able to send the result of this form select tag into my Angular2 form?

My entire article-input.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Article} from './article';
import {ArticleService} from "./article.service";
import {ErrorService} from "../errors/error.service";
import { FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators, Control } from     '@angular/common';
import {TopicService} from "../topics/topic.service";
import {Topic} from "../topics/topic";



@Component({
    selector: 'my-article-input',
    template: `
         <section class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">        
            <form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input [ngFormControl]="myForm.find('title')"     type="text" id="title" class="form-control" #input [value]="article?.title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <input [ngFormControl]="myForm.find('content')" type="text" id="content" class="form-control" #input [value]="article?.content">
                </div>
                <select [ngFormControl]="myForm.find('topic')" id="topic"  class="form-control" required>
                    <option  *ngFor="let a of topics" [value]="a">{{a.title}}</option>
                </select>                                 
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">{{ !article ? 'Add Article' : 'Save Article' }}</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onCancel()" *ngIf="article">Cancel</button>
            </form>
        </section>
`

})

export class ArticleInputComponent implements OnInit {

    myForm: ControlGroup;

    article: Article = null;

    constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder, private _articleService: ArticleService, private _errorService: ErrorService, private _topicService: TopicService ) {}

    topics: Topic[];

    onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.myForm.value.topic.title);

        if (this.article) {
            // Edit
            this.article.content = this.myForm.value.content;
            this.article.title = this.myForm.value.title;
            this.article.topicId = this.myForm.value.topic.topicId;
            this._articleService.updateArticle(this.article)
                .subscribe(
                    data => console.log(data),
                    error => this._errorService.handleError(error)
                );
            this.article = null;
        } else  {
            const article: Article = new Article(this.myForm.value.content, this.myForm.value.title, null, 'DummyArticleInput', this.myForm.value.topic);
            this._articleService.addArticle(article)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        console.log(data);
                        this._articleService.articles.push(data);
                    },
                    error => this._errorService.handleError(error)
                );
        }


    }

    onCancel() {
        this.article = null;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],
            content: ['', Validators.required],
            topic: ['', Validators.required]
        });

    this._articleService.articleIsEdit.subscribe(
         article => {
            this.article = article;
        }
    );

    this._topicService.getTopics().subscribe(
            topics => {
                this.topics = topics;
                this._topicService.topics = topics
            },
            error => this._errorService.handleError(error)
        );

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this is to not use the myForm element with ngFormControl for objects/form field that are going to be references to other objects within the application. Instead what needed to be done was as follows.

1. Create topics, topic, and a selectedTopic

   ```
   topics: Topic[];
   topic = '';
   selectedTopic = '';
   ```
2. Add a select tag with an option tag to the form for a user to be able to select the topic they want by binding with ngModel to 'topic'

   ```
   <select [ngModel]="topic" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
      <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of topics">{{i.title}}</option>
   </select>
   ```
3. Create an onChange method that will update this.selectedTopic based on the user selecting a topic in the form

   ```
   onChange(newValue) {
     this.selectedTopic = newValue;
     console.log(this.selectedTopic);
     console.log(this.selectedTopic.topicId);
   }
   ```
4. Then in the onSubmit method use the myForm.value's for the info coming from the actual form, and use the databinding on this.selectedTopic for the topic that is being selected

   ```
   onSubmit() {

   if (this.article) {
       // Edit
       this.article.content = this.myForm.value.content;
       this.article.title = this.myForm.value.title;
       this.article.topicId = this.selectedTopic;
       this._articleService.updateArticle(this.article)
           .subscribe(
               data => console.log(data),
               error => this._errorService.handleError(error)
           );
       this.article = null;
   } else  {
       const article: Article = new Article(this.myForm.value.content, this.myForm.value.title, null,  'dummyUserName', 'dummyUserId', this.selectedTopic.topicId);
       this._articleService.addArticle(article)
           .subscribe(
               data => {
                  // console.log('what comes back from addArticle is: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                   this._articleService.articles.push(data);
               },
               error => this._errorService.handleError(error)
           );
   }
   ```

From where we started, we have now gotten to a place where everything works and the object getting created looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5758c2e173fd33e04092c87e"), "content" : "c66", "title" : "t66", "user" : ObjectId("5755e5be96162f52a4f01dd8"), "topic" : ObjectId("57572d92e802307d199f0afa"), "__v" : 0 }
```

For reference, the entire (working) article-input.component.ts file looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Article} from './article';
import {ArticleService} from "./article.service";
import {ErrorService} from "../errors/error.service";
import { FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators, Control } from '@angular/common';
import {TopicService} from "../topics/topic.service";
import {Topic} from "../topics/topic";



@Component({
    selector: 'my-article-input',
    template: `
         <section class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input [ngFormControl]="myForm.find('title')" type="text" id="title" class="form-control" #input [value]="article?.title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <input [ngFormControl]="myForm.find('content')" type="text" id="content" class="form-control" #input [value]="article?.content">
                </div>

                <select [ngModel]="topic" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
                  <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of topics">{{i.title}}</option>
                </select>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >{{ !article ? 'Add Article' : 'Save Article' }}</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onCancel()" *ngIf="article">Cancel</button>
            </form>
        </section>
    `

})

export class ArticleInputComponent implements OnInit {

    myForm: ControlGroup;

    article: Article = null;

    constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder, private _articleService: ArticleService, private _errorService: ErrorService, private _topicService: TopicService ) {}

    topics: Topic[];
    topic = '';
    selectedTopic = '';


    onChange(newValue) {
        this.selectedTopic = newValue;
        console.log(this.selectedTopic);
        console.log(this.selectedTopic.topicId);
    }

    onSubmit() {

        if (this.article) {
            // Edit
            this.article.content = this.myForm.value.content;
            this.article.title = this.myForm.value.title;
            this.article.topicId = this.selectedTopic;
            this._articleService.updateArticle(this.article)
                .subscribe(
                    data => console.log(data),
                    error => this._errorService.handleError(error)
                );
            this.article = null;
        } else  {
            const article: Article = new Article(this.myForm.value.content, this.myForm.value.title, null,  'dummyUserName', 'dummyUserId', this.selectedTopic.topicId);
            this._articleService.addArticle(article)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                       // console.log('what comes back from addArticle is: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                        this._articleService.articles.push(data);
                    },
                    error => this._errorService.handleError(error)
                );
        }


    }

    onCancel() {
        this.article = null;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],
            content: ['', Validators.required],
            topic: ['', Validators.required]
        });

        this._articleService.articleIsEdit.subscribe(
            article => {
                this.article = article;
            }
        );

        this._topicService.getTopics().subscribe(
                topics => {
                    this.topics = topics;
                    this._topicService.topics = topics
                },
                error => this._errorService.handleError(error)
            );

    }


}
```

my topic.ts angular model looks like this:

```
export class Topic {
    description: string;
    title: string;
    username: string;
    topicId: string;
    userId: string;

    constructor (description: string, title: string, topicId?: string, username?: string, userId?: string) {
        this.description = description;
        this.title = title;
        this.topicId = topicId;
        this.username = username;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

the article.service.ts looks like this:

```
addArticle(article: Article) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(article);
    console.log(body);
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token') ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token') : '';
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/article' + token, body, {headers: headers})
        .map(response => {
            const data = response.json().obj;
            let article = new Article(data.content, data.title, data._id, data.user.firstName, data.user, data.topicId);
            return article;
        })
        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}
```

an in the backend in Node my article.js looks like this:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    User.findById(decoded.user._id, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                title: 'An Error occured',
                error: err
            });
        }
        var article = new Article({
            content: req.body.content,
            title: req.body.title,
            user: doc,
            topic: req.body.topicId
        });
        console.log(req.body);
        article.save(function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    title: 'An Error occured',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            doc.articles.push(result);
            doc.save();
            res.status(201).json({
                article: 'Saved Article',
                obj: result
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I hope this helps others who had the same issue as I did.